# Get records created Today in Salesforce Flow's Get Records element

Tags: salesforce-flow

I want to get all the Order records created today in a Salesforce Schedule Triggered Flow .
I have created a formula variable as-
var = DATETIMEVALUE( TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) + "-" + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())) + "-" + TEXT(DAY(TODAY())) + " 00:00:00")

Using it in Get Records Element filter criteria as-
Created Date *Greater Than Equal To* var.

Is this a correct approach?

If no, please suggest a proper solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be your best approach. If you find that it works then great but have you tried a Get where Created Date is Greater Than or Equal to {!$Flow.CurrentDate}?

Comment: Hi @Brian Biddi, I have tried {!$Flow.CurrentDate}, but it doesn't work, because Created Date is a combination of date/time whereas {!$Flow.CurrentDate} returns only the Date.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new formula resource with date Data type . Formula should be DATETIMEVALUE(TODAY()) .